# unable to find data in examples dashboard in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I just started working on apache superset. I wanted to try the example dataset that superset was offering. i ran the command

```
superset load_examples
```

in the virtual environment. The execution->

```
No PIL installation found
2022-02-03 16:41:54,811:INFO:superset.utils.screenshots:No PIL installation found
Loading examples metadata and related data into examples
Creating default CSS templates
Loading [World Bank's Health Nutrition and Population Stats]
Creating table [World Bank Health Data] reference
Creating a World's Health Bank dashboard
Loading [Birth names]
Creating some slices
Creating a dashboard
Loading [Random long/lat data]
Creating table reference
Creating a slice
Loading [Country Map data]
Creating table reference
Creating a slice
Loading [San Francisco population polygons]
Creating table San Francisco Population Polygons reference
Loading [Flights data]
Done loading table!
Loading [BART lines]
Creating table San Franciso BART Lines reference
Loading [Multi Line]
Creating table [World Bank Health Data] reference
Creating a World's Health Bank dashboard
Creating some slices
Creating a dashboard
Loading [Misc Charts] dashboard
Creating the dashboard
Loading DECK.gl demo
Loading deck.gl dashboard
Creating Scatterplot slice
Creating Screen Grid slice
Creating Hex slice
Creating Grid slice
Creating Polygon slice
Creating Arc slice
Creating Path slice
Creating a dashboard
```

Seems like it installed without any problems. Now when i go to my superset dashboard, i find  `World Bank's Data` i click on it, and all the charts say

```
No results were returned for this query. If you expected results to be returned, ensure any filters are configured properly and the datasource contains data for the selected time range.
```

Then i check all the example dashboards, all of them have the same written on them.
I dont know what could be the issue. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Run `superset fab create-admin` and create a user with Username(admin) to be able to load the examples.
Then `superset init` after `load_examples`

Comment: i completely set up my superset first and then i got to know about example datasets. so i have already created an admin user, a default user and tried on both but nothing is displayed